GoogleチャットのWebHookで発信する文字の色を変えたい
GoogleチャットのWebHookを使ってメッセージを自動発信するプログラムを作成しています。
ただ単に自動発信することは出来たのですが、発信する文字を装飾することを行いたいです。
太字は、マークダウン記法を使えば可能なことはわかりました。
文字色を変更する場合に何をどうしたらよいか全くわからずご教授いただきたいです。

詳しくないですが、 https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/format-messages?hl=ja を見ると、色を付けられるのは 「カード メッセージ」だけなのかも知れません。

ありがとうございます。
大変申し訳ございません。ご指摘の通り、「カードメッセージ」で実現したら色を変えることに成功しました。
コメントありがとうございました。
